# chef-solo ssl warning when provisioning

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

When using vagrant and chef as provisioner, I've got this warning:

````
[web] Chef 11.12.2 Omnibus package is already installed.
[web] Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2014-04-10T14:48:46+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-04-10T14:48:46+00:00] WARN:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

```
  # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
  ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

  # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
  verify_api_cert true
```

To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
`knife ssl check` command like so:

```
  knife ssl check -c /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/solo.rb
```

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
````

Would be nice to know what kind of settings does chef requires in Vagrantfile to fix this issue.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This warning was introduced in Chef 11.12.0. See the [release notes](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/11-stable/RELEASE_NOTES.md#unsecure-ssl-verification-mode-now-triggers-a-warning) for details:

> When `ssl_verify_mode` is set to `:verify_none`, Chef will print a
>   warning. Use `knife ssl check` to test SSL connectivity and then add
>   `ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer` to your configuration file to fix the
>   warning. Though `:verify_none` is currently the default, this will be
>   changed in a future release, so users are encouraged to be proactive in
>   testing and updating their SSL configuration.

To fix this warning in Vagrant, you have to amend the `solo.rb` config file it creates in the VM. With Vagrant you can use the [`custom_config_path`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_common.html) option for that.

You can thus amend your Vagrantfile like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    # the next line is added
    chef.custom_config_path = "Vagrantfile.chef"
  end
end
```

This makes Vagrant include the contents of the *local* file `Vagrantfile.chef` into the generated solo.rb, the file thus needs to be present on your host system, not the VM.

Then, create a new file `Vagrantfile.chef` in the directory where you also keep your Vagrantfile with the following content:

```
Chef::Config.ssl_verify_mode = :verify_peer
```

The next run of `vagrant provision` should no longer print the warning.

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue when working with test-kitchen.

If that is also the case for you, note that this value can also be directly configured inside `.kitchen.yml`.

If your standard provisioner block looks like:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
```

you can just add the `solo_rb` key with the `ssl_verify_mode` option:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_solo
  solo_rb:
    ssl_verify_mode: verify_peer
```

and the generated solo.rb will have this option set.

Answer (score 8):

I know the original question was about Vagrant, but for people using the `knife-solo` gem and encountering this error, just add the following line to `.chef/knife.rb`:

```
ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer
```

The `knife-solo` gem will take that value and put it into the `solo.rb` file that gets uploaded onto the server, which is the main configuration file passed to `chef-solo`.